# Events Dashboard: Role-based count assumes only one role per participant?

Tags: civievent, participants

After some testing I've come to the conclusion that even if all of the participant roles are set as 'counted', if you give any participant more than one role (e.g. the might be a 'host' and a 'speaker') then CiviCRM does not include them in the count, or to be precise it includes them in the 'Not Counted Due to Role' number that is displayed on the Events Dashboard.

This also then breaks the Max Participants setting in the event configuration, enabling continued online registration, giving rise to potential venue capacity issues.

Given that it is both do-able and sensible in many use cases to apply multiple roles to event participants (I certainly have at least one client that makes extensive use of the ability to apply multiple roles to event participants), I would consider this to be a bug.

Comment: Have you replicated on Demo? If so then probably worth reporting in GitLab

Comment: Done. Confirmed and reported on Gitlab. Thanks

Comment: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/issues/76